# Create a single instance of an always running system service for all applications

Tags: android, service, system

I do experiments with SystemServices in Android that I build for using on a machine control.

My own SystemService is registered in SystemServer.
To me it looks like if I call context.getSystemService("my service name") in different apps then every app gets a new instance of this service.
For my system it is important to have one global service instance to memorize and deliver data from and to all apps that get this service. (and to do other things depending on the machine, they require a global server as well)

Is it possible to create only one single service instance in Android that all apps get returned when they query for it?

Comment: Return START_REDELIVER_INTENT flag from onStartCommand and use Foreground service.

Comment: @DeepakS.Gavkar This impossible for my service, it is a system level service, not an app level service.